# How to send audio stream using UDP socket in ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, audio-streaming

How do you send audio and video stream data over UDP sockets. Also, how do you stream audio file from server.

i am using this project: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

but some data not send how to solve this problem

send nsdata code is there:

```
  NSString *host = addrField.text;
    if ([host length] == 0)
    {
        [self logError:@"Address required"];
        return;
    }

    int port = [portField.text intValue];
    if (port <= 0 || port > 65535)
    {
        [self logError:@"Valid port required"];
        return;
    }
    NSString *msg = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"11" ofType:@"mp4"];
    if ([msg length] == 0)
    {
        [self logError:@"Message required"];
        return;
    }

    NSData* datafile =[[NSData alloc]init];
    datafile= [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:msg];

    NSUInteger length = [datafile length]; // total size of data
    NSLog(@"real data len >>%lu",(unsigned long)length);

    NSUInteger chunkSize =9000; // divide data into 10 mb
    NSUInteger offset = 0;
    countfordatbunch=0;
    do {
        // get the chunk location
        NSUInteger thisChunkSize = length - offset > chunkSize ? chunkSize : length - offset;
        // get the chunk
        data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(char *)[datafile bytes] + offset
                                    length:thisChunkSize
                              freeWhenDone:NO];
        [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
        udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self  delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        //omitted error checking
        [udpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:nil];
        [udpSocket bindToPort:port error:nil];
        [udpSocket joinMulticastGroup:host error:nil];
        [udpSocket beginReceiving:nil];
        [udpSocket sendData:data toHost:host port:port withTimeout:10 tag:tag];
           offset += thisChunkSize;
        countfordatbunch++;

    } while (offset < length);
    msg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",countfordatbunch];
    data = [msg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //omitted error checking
    [udpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:nil];
    [udpSocket bindToPort:port error:nil];
    [udpSocket joinMulticastGroup:host error:nil];
    [udpSocket beginReceiving:nil];
    // [udpSocket receiveWithTimeout:10 tag:1];
    [udpSocket sendData:data toHost:host port:port withTimeout:10 tag:tag];
    NSLog(@"countfordatbunch >>>%d",countfordatbunch);
```

and receive code there:

```
- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
                                           fromAddress:(NSData *)address
                                     withFilterContext:(id)filterContext
{
[arraySoundData addObject:data];
NSLog(@"arraySoundData>>%d",arraySoundData.count);
msg1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
int count=[msg1 integerValue];
NSLog(@"msg_count >>%d",count);
if       (((arraySoundData.count==count+1)&&arraySoundData.count!=1)||arraySoundData.count==count)
{

    [self logMessage:FORMAT(@"RECV: %@", @"message send")];

    sound = [NSMutableData data];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<[arraySoundData count]; i++)
    {
        NSData *soundPacket = [arraySoundData objectAtIndex:i];
        [sound appendData:soundPacket];

    }
    NSLog(@"%@",sound);
    NSUInteger length1 = [sound length];
    NSLog(@"data len >>%lu",(unsigned long)length1);

    NSFileManager *fileManager =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *fileName = @"file.mp4";
    NSLog(@"%@",fileName);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSLog(@"%@",dataPath);
    BOOL filecreationSuccess = [fileManager createFileAtPath:dataPath contents:sound attributes:nil];
    if(filecreationSuccess == NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create the html file");
    }

    NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataPath];
    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];
    NSLog(@"%@",moviePlayerController);
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    //moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(150, 250, 150, 150);
    moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    moviePlayerController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    [moviePlayerController play];

    [arraySoundData removeAllObjects];
    //msg1=@"";
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)arraySoundData.count);
    [self.modalViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

}

}
```

Comment: how to send current recording audio by udp socket